# Add shared contacts to Outlook 2007 address book

Tags: exchange, outlook, public-folders, contacts

Hello we just upgraded from exchange 2003 to 2010.  2010 seems to be pushing people to stop using public folders.  Public folders had the nice feature that you could see the contacts of the public folder in your address book.  I haven't found a way to add shared contacts to the Outlook address book.  How do you do it?  If I am unable to find the solution I will likely have to go through the hassle of migrating the public folders over.  I was having a problem with that so I went the route of shared contacts.

Comment: Just as note - the 2010 "do not use public folders" mantra was pretty much immediately thrown out in 2013, which redid and reintroduced public folders. While wondering why anyone would now update to 2010 (instead of 2013) - I would not bother about "do not use public folders" as long term issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your contact records in the Active directory.  After all it is a directory server.